# C# DateTime Parser Bug?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

given:

```
        DateTime parsedDate;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact("0992012", "ddMyyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out parsedDate))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NO");
        }
```

Why is the output NO? Is this a bug?

Comment: could be unrelated, but is a single 'M' valid for a month identifier?  I thought the values were 'MM' or 'MMM'

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, it's valid. It means "1 or 2 digits, no padding".

Comment: I have tried your code, and it throws an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I just used ParseExact in order to get error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a bad format, basically - I don't know whether it's *specified* whether or not it should be accepted, but including a variable-width numeric field beside other numeric fields without any delimiters is a *really bad idea*.

I *suspect* the parser sees this as 09 followed by 92 in a "take 1 or 2 digits for the month" and doesn't realize that the 2 is meant to belong to the year part. That's what the Noda Time parser would do, at least...

If you can't change your input format, you should massage the data in-place before trying to parse it - e.g.

```
if (text.Length == 7)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, 2) + "0" + text.Substring(2);
}
// Now parse as ddMMyyyy
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! 

"09-9-2012", "dd-M-yyyy" => works great! I thought the parser can parse any input wiht a specific format.

I filter my input and add the delimiters... silly workaround but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it has something to do with the `M` code being a one or two-digit month. Without a delimiter, it's not trivial to determine where the month ends and the year begins.